# Service - Start Delay

Tags: service, startup

I would like to start a service manually but as the service starts (Green progress bar) I'd like it to wait 30secs and then start the service. Is there a way of doing this?

I've tried adding a "AutoStartDelay" and a "StartDelay" DWORD value in the registry but not quite sure if its that simple?